# how to read XMLof island.verification response in PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ID="_85760fa1-6150-4cb8-a889-dc7822e3503a" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2017-01-31T16:19:19.7661269Z" Destination="http://ashirinfo.ml/test.php"
    xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <Issuer
        xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">Innskraning
    </Issuer>
    <Signature
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
            <Reference URI="">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                <DigestValue>jvG4EAVESo6/a6JhR39cHv8h47iNDPAuX2qAP9OQ748=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>t6P7i21Ri2lobnd+10qZMZ//N7MCgEidntxSEtsdV0r3IK7Tc9R4nsE5oXjl5nMtWmQ7AjgcAA1sWt+LmeTlCqV2190UyGH3G1YGucDoI2QJ5o74XIsKwdilXJYxyzIkDWil201lzeEQbhRp5HbKe1Wuzi89m/uey28RyLhYXklIieFtS90pUHn3hTwjPTxdRzPPuPdOIx0YIwHTiWO1nvzAcN0CVTMm6zGFjrb+5uRR8N/LcOsG7X5Se639CKhkhmWK6ZBTFW1HHMf4ZSAzGuPEBcnNC7skTbpo5kD0kRVH+H+d9zLblZaf1+l7ks5KevMsfdtX4OwTAACMbazfRw==</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
            <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
    <Status>
        <StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
    </Status>
    <Assertion Version="2.0" ID="_6d169c05-0cb6-4370-9030-d30ab20c2d84" IssueInstant="2017-01-31T16:19:19.7661269Z"
        xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        <Issuer>Innskraning</Issuer>
        <Subject>
            <NameID NameQualifier="island.is" />
            <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                <SubjectConfirmationData Address="182.187.39.131" NotOnOrAfter="2017-01-31T16:24:19.7661269Z" Recipient="http://ashirinfo.ml/test.php" />
            </SubjectConfirmation>
        </Subject>
        <Conditions NotBefore="2017-01-31T16:18:49.7661269Z" NotOnOrAfter="2017-01-31T16:24:19.7661269Z">
            <AudienceRestriction>
                <Audience>ashirinfo.ml</Audience>
            </AudienceRestriction>
        </Conditions>
        <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2017-01-31T16:19:19.7661269Z">
            <SubjectLocality Address="10.160.97.130" />
            <AuthnContext>
                <AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:TLSClient</AuthnContextClassRef>
            </AuthnContext>
        </AuthnStatement>
        <AttributeStatement>
            <Attribute Name="UserSSN" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" FriendlyName="Kennitala">
                <AttributeValue xsi:type="xsd:string">2604783899</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="Name" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" FriendlyName="Nafn">
                <AttributeValue xsi:type="xsd:string">Birgir Örn Birgisson</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="Authentication" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" FriendlyName="Auðkenning">
                <AttributeValue xsi:type="xsd:string">Rafræn símaskilríki</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="IPAddress" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" FriendlyName="IPTala">
                <AttributeValue xsi:type="xsd:string">182.187.39.131</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="UserAgent" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" FriendlyName="NotandaStrengur">
                <AttributeValue xsi:type="xsd:string">Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="DestinationSSN" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" FriendlyName="KennitalaMóttakanda">
                <AttributeValue xsi:type="xsd:string">6906071310</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="Mobile" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" FriendlyName="Farsímanúmer">
                <AttributeValue xsi:type="xsd:string">+354-6505040</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
        </AttributeStatement>
    </Assertion>
</Response>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ID="_85760fa1-6150-4cb8-a889-dc7822e3503a" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2017-01-31T16:19:19.7661269Z" Destination="http://ashirinfo.ml/test.php"
    xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <Issuer
        xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">Innskraning
    </Issuer>
    <Signature
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
            <Reference URI="">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                <DigestValue>jvG4EAVESo6/a6JhR39cHv8h47iNDPAuX2qAP9OQ748=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>t6P7i21Ri2lobnd+10qZMZ//N7MCgEidntxSEtsdV0r3IK7Tc9R4nsE5oXjl5nMtWmQ7AjgcAA1sWt+LmeTlCqV2190UyGH3G1YGucDoI2QJ5o74XIsKwdilXJYxyzIkDWil201lzeEQbhRp5HbKe1Wuzi89m/uey28RyLhYXklIieFtS90pUHn3hTwjPTxdRzPPuPdOIx0YIwHTiWO1nvzAcN0CVTMm6zGFjrb+5uRR8N/LcOsG7X5Se639CKhkhmWK6ZBTFW1HHMf4ZSAzGuPEBcnNC7skTbpo5kD0kRVH+H+d9zLblZaf1+l7ks5KevMsfdtX4OwTAACMbazfRw==</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
            <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>MIIGDDCCBPSgAwIBAgICHRwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwgZIxCzAJBgNVBAYTAklTMRMwEQYDVQQFEwo1MjEwMDAyNzkwMRYwFAYDVQQKEw1BdWRrZW5uaSBlaGYuMSMwIQYDVQQLExpVdGdlZmFuZGkgYnVuYWRhcnNraWxyaWtqYTEWMBQGA1UECxMNTWlsbGlza2lscmlraTEZMBcGA1UEAxMQVHJhdXN0dXIgYnVuYWR1cjAeFw0xNjA3MTQxNTExMzdaFw0xODA3MTQxNTExMzdaMIHCMQswCQYDVQQGEwJJUzEeMBwGA1UECgwVw55qw7PDsHNrcsOhIMONc2xhbmRzMRgwFgYDVQQLEw9CdW5hZGFyc2tpbHJpa2kxJTAjBgNVBAsMHFVuZGlycml0dW4gZcOwYSBhdcOwa2VubmluZyAxHTAbBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWDnZlcmtAaXNsYW5kLmlzMRMwEQYDVQQFEwo2NTAzNzYwNjQ5MR4wHAYDVQQDExVJbm5za3JhbmluZyBJc2xhbmQuaXMwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQDGunlc4jwRyE+W0MiWfT6sdXvSMwsRTg3rTlw50/rbjUuGGMhYerYFl7itc/i0ZsMbGetq8Z/BFnEIqhY/zsHFk/DRRBLze6HIOLYAqMn9LEGVhquzwfQW8dCB7LEr+W/YdbdTp6vkbiE2h2PDtb8VYpH103Oa8FzplVKSwZLSRhiJAeI9Rs7Z+2SlNhTje9tUxzWInxtSTmnjB/YXISJgfwtrt/5Ws1Z0CX/VgQ4+ZsnmN7t+8AeDwv41SkJCjT7R1Vn5IKm3QNBzS+q414H4eCa1O2my7NehvLBvrjeHegsP4mtYp8bNJ6W/IxsXDLY3AKe2IM72+AAytXlMONahAgMBAAGjggI4MIICNDAMBgNVHRMBAf8EAjAAMIIBHAYDVR0gBIIBEzCCAQ8wggELBglggmABAgEBBAEwgf0wgcQGCCsGAQUFBwICMIG3GoG0VGhpcyBjZXJ0aWZpY2F0ZSBpcyBpbnRlbmRlZCBmb3IgZGlnaXRhbCBzaWduYXR1cmVzIGFuZCBhdXRoZW50aWNhdGlvbi4gVGhpcyBjZXJ0aWZpY2F0ZSBmdWxmaWxzIHRoZSByZXF1aXJlbWVudHMgb2Ygbm9ybWFsaXplZCBjZXJ0aWZpY2F0ZSBwb2xpY3kgKE5DUCkgZGVmaW5lZCBpbiBFVFNJIFRTIDEwMiAwNDIuMDQGCCsGAQUFBwIBFihodHRwOi8vY3AuYXVka2VubmkuaXMvdHJhdXN0dXJidW5hZHVyL2NwMHMGCCsGAQUFBwEBBGcwZTAjBggrBgEFBQcwAoYXaHR0cDovL29jc3AuYXVka2VubmkuaXMwPgYHYIJgAgFjBoYzaHR0cDovL2NkcC5hdWRrZW5uaS5pcy9za2lscmlraS90cmF1c3R1cmJ1bmFkdXIucDdiMAsGA1UdDwQEAwIF4DAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBRv7NsRLAEDaxtgrrb4aNlAAc2OODBCBgNVHR8EOzA5MDegNaAzhjFodHRwOi8vY3JsLmF1ZGtlbm5pLmlzL3RyYXVzdHVyYnVuYWR1ci9sYXRlc3QuY3JsMB0GA1UdDgQWBBTXlBUp1axlTP9Rp2js7gSEmHKVzDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOCAQEABbDwqym5k1pmai/UL49pceeJnWSTvpZOabAYXOb/CeOM6iombgSgi/F8nXtZ49QCAZEdlB7S+jKL/6btqnWvE3FtaZpDzU1LdkzvUlJSYJlWCRgQV8g2uLz78QibychcIjlT2j0tx32TTg9kd64KX+k7/YjP+QJ1rpPkvWT7DNdJTrnLhCE01/qgGza2D+3c7Tav7WpqSv1CN7AY0RtDsEDBoH4os+5SRCX0+oOQ7ucv+nbaOYggzz06w7yfUdUQtrxS97fJwuH7hspD50lRdSlzKR38GPcL9E54OMz6Znw8ntw2htNZ1p0K/97sYJUUaHJWSM7u5655JyvpeEjKeA==</X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
    <Status>
        <StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
    </Status>
    <Assertion Version="2.0" ID="_6d169c05-0cb6-4370-9030-d30ab20c2d84" IssueInstant="2017-01-31T16:19:19.7661269Z"
        xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        <Issuer>Innskraning</Issuer>
        <Subject>
            <NameID NameQualifier="island.is" />
            <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                <SubjectConfirmationData Address="182.187.39.131" NotOnOrAfter="2017-01-31T16:24:19.7661269Z" Recipient="http://ashirinfo.ml/test.php" />
            </SubjectConfirmation>
        </Subject>
        <Conditions NotBefore="2017-01-31T16:18:49.7661269Z" NotOnOrAfter="2017-01-31T16:24:19.7661269Z">
            <AudienceRestriction>
                <Audience>ashirinfo.ml</Audience>
            </AudienceRestriction>
        </Conditions>
        <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2017-01-31T16:19:19.7661269Z">
            <SubjectLocality Address="10.160.97.130" />
            <AuthnContext>
                <AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:TLSClient</AuthnContextClassRef>
            </AuthnContext>
        </AuthnStatement>
        <AttributeStatement>
            <Attribute Name="UserSSN" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" FriendlyName="Kennitala">
                <AttributeValue xsi:type="xsd:string">2604783899</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="Name" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" FriendlyName="Nafn">
                <AttributeValue xsi:type="xsd:string">Birgir Örn Birgisson</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="Authentication" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" FriendlyName="Auðkenning">
                <AttributeValue xsi:type="xsd:string">Rafræn símaskilríki</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="IPAddress" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" FriendlyName="IPTala">
                <AttributeValue xsi:type="xsd:string">182.187.39.131</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="UserAgent" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" FriendlyName="NotandaStrengur">
                <AttributeValue xsi:type="xsd:string">Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="DestinationSSN" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" FriendlyName="KennitalaMóttakanda">
                <AttributeValue xsi:type="xsd:string">6906071310</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="Mobile" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" FriendlyName="Farsímanúmer">
                <AttributeValue xsi:type="xsd:string">+354-6505040</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
        </AttributeStatement>
    </Assertion>
```

> In Overall XML I Want to read this tags through PHP but after many try
>   am not success please Help me

```
<Attribute Name="UserSSN" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" FriendlyName="Kennitala">
                    <AttributeValue xsi:type="xsd:string">2604783899</AttributeValue>
                </Attribute>
                <Attribute Name="Name" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" FriendlyName="Nafn">
                    <AttributeValue xsi:type="xsd:string">Birgir Örn Birgisson</AttributeValue>
                </Attribute>
```

> from these tags my require value two require values are first **2604783899** >and second is **Birgir Örn Birgisson** please tell me how i read this using PHP

Answer (score 0):

You can  use [xml_parser_create & xml_parse_into_struct](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php). Try this :

```
$p = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($p, $xml, $vals, $index);//$xml is your xml data
xml_parser_free($p);
echo "<pre>";

$results=array();
foreach($vals as $key=>$val){
    if(strcmp($val['tag'],'ATTRIBUTEVALUE') == 0){
        $results[]=$val['value'];
    }
}
print_r($results);//resultant array get the value desired.
```

[DEMO HERE](https://eval.in/728811)

Comment: Thanks alot its works i appreciate your effort can you please tell me how its actual work ?

Comment: @MuhammadAshir if it helped then mark it as answer. `xml_parse_into_struct` creates an array of values and indexes in above code i'm using values to get the data. i have attached a link on the top visit it.